# Apply Sharp with blue lines

Tags: export, import, unreal-engine

In my model I have this blue lines. I know that I can remove it with Crtl + E -> Clear Sharp, but I think I don't need it. When I import this model to Unreal Engine, I need it to look like on the first image with edges.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines will disappear anyway if you import your first sharp model in Unity. But if the lines annoy you while working, simply turn off their visibility in Overlays menu [image]